# Does stop() Only Work With animate()?

Tags: jquery

I've got a simple setup where when one hovers over the #ProductLink li, #ProductListing ul opens, then closes when the mouse moves away.

```
$(document).ready(   function() {
    $("#ProductLink").hover(
      function() {
        $('#ProductListing').slideDown(200);
      },
      function() {
        $('#ProductListing').slideUp(200);
      }
    )   } )
```

This works but the predictable side effect is that multiple passes over and out of #ProductLink cue the sliding up and down.  I have tried to use stop() to keep this from happening without success and am wondering if stop() only works with animate().

If stop() does work in this instance then I would appreciate a pointer in the right direction.

Thanks -

george

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stop()` *does* work with `slideUp()` and `slideDown()`

Like so:

```
$("#ProductLink").hover(
    function() {
        $('#ProductListing').stop().slideDown(200);
    }, function() {
        $('#ProductListing').stop().slideUp(200);
    }
);
```

When using sliders, you'd want to finalize the ongoing animation as well, so you can pass booleans to the `stop()` method to gain more control:

```
$("#ProductLink").hover(
    function() {
        $('#ProductListing').stop(false,true).slideDown(200);
    }, function() {
        $('#ProductListing').stop(false,true).slideUp(200);
    }
);
```

Comment: The booleans did it, I missed that in the documentation.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of [the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/stop), it stops any and all animation. I just created a test-case on my machine, and `$.stop()` did indeed stop `$.slideDown()` as expected.

```
  $("a.stop").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".bigBox").stop(); // in the process of animation
  });
```